# How to make emacs recognize a bash script that ends in .sh?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get Emacs to understand that my script is bash.

I tried adding `-*- bash -*-` to the first line of the file, but it still opens in `Shell-script[sh]` mode. I can rename the file to give it a bash extension (currently it's `.sh`) but this might break some existing code.

Is there some way to give Emacs this hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C-h m` should tell you:

```
[...]
shell-specific features.  Shell script files can use the `sh-shell' local
variable to indicate the shell variant to be used for the file.
[...]
```

so adding `-*- sh-shell: bash -*-` on the first line should do the trick.

Comment: `auto-mode-alist` should be mentioned here. `C-h v` `auto-mode-alist`

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right answer. Is the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) not sufficient? Either way I think it should be added on the *second* line.

Comment: @jagrg: Indeed the shebang line can do the trick.  My answer presumes we're talking about a file without the shebang line.